# Can the word recipient be used to refer to objects?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, vocabulary

The reason why I'm asking this question is because all the main online dictionaries provide the same meaning for this word, that is: a person who receives something. They don't mention objects used to store something, like water, for example.

Isn't a bottle a recipient used to store liquids?

If we go to Google images and type "water recipient" it shows us a lot of bottles.

Cambridge definition for recipient:

> a person who receives something
>
> a person or organization that receives something, such as money, a prize, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A **recipient**, as your definition states, is normally a person or an organisation. You may be after the similar word **receptacle**.

> A container, device, etc., that receives or holds something

*(Dictionary.com)*

As in:

> Please take a **receptacle** to the water fountain.

A "water recipient" to me would be a person who is given water. But it sounds quite formal, and I would only expect to hear it in situations like emergency aid.

> 5000 water recipients have benefited from our emergency bottled water program.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what to do because I've been studying English for a decade or so and I still make this kinda mistakes sometimes. I was revising a text I wrote in 2017 and I noticed this word there and I thought I should verify it could actually mean a "container". But it can't.

Comment: Don't worry, even native speakers can confuse similar sounding works like recipient and receptacle!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, recipient can be used for objects, for example, in chemistry.

[Khan Academy (about chemical bonds)](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/chemistry--of-life/chemical-bonds-and-reactions/a/chemical-bonds-article):

> In general, the loss of an electron by one atom and gain of an
>   electron by another atom must happen at the same time: in order for a
>   sodium atom to lose an electron, it needs to have a suitable
>   **recipient** like a chlorine atom.

[Wikipedia (about reducing agents)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reducing_agent)

> If any chemical is an electron donor (reducing agent), another must be
>   an electron **recipient** (oxidizing agent).

Comment: Thank you, so it can actually refer to objects but not in the sense of a "container", right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Container "holds" something, and recipient "receives" something. Anyway, "recipient" is not commonly used for objects in everyday life; it's a technical term used in chemistry, physics, biology, etc.